# Clear Contents of unprotected Specific Range in a protected sheet

Tags: vba, excel, union

I want to clear the unprotected contents of a protected sheet within a specific range. for example when i run VBA it will clear the contents ranging from A1002:F1301 and G1002: AZ1301. The mentioned ranges are unprotected. I want only the cell between these range to be clear but not format or any other change.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835589.aspx

Answer (score 0):

> <sup>Since your example ranges (e.g. A1002:F1301 and G1002:AZ1301) do not actually have any unreferenced columns or rows between them, I am going to change your example to A1002:F1301 and H1002:AZ1301 which leaves column G unreferenced with two [Areas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa174786.aspx) in a discontiguous range.</sup>

Use something similar to one of the following first two methods.

```
with worksheets("Sheet1")
    .range("A1002:F1301, H1002:AZ1301").clearcontents
    'alternative with Union
    union(.range("A1002:F1301"), .range("H1002:AZ1301")).clearcontents
    'do NOT use the following - it includes all the cells in between
    .range("A1002:F1301", "H1002:AZ1301").clearcontents
end with
```

The first method is shorthand for the second's [Union method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834621.aspx). Note the difference between the first and the third. The third is NOT recommended for your purposes as it includes all of the cells between the two ranges (e.g. A1002:AZ1301).

The [Range.ClearContents method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa223828.aspx) only clears the values unlike the [Range.Clear](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa223824.aspx) which clears values and  formats.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used. It is a mixture of code that I have gotten from different answers to fit my needs. In the first example, I wanted it to clear the unlocked cells only on a specific sheet.

```
Sub ClearProgressNotes_JAN()

 With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range
Set ws = Worksheets("JAN")
Set Rng = ws.Range("b9:ay109")
Dim OutRng As Range
On Error Resume Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each Rng In Rng
    If Rng.Locked = False Then
        If OutRng.Count = 0 Then
            Set OutRng = Rng
        Else
            Set OutRng = Union(OutRng, Rng)
        End If
    End If
Next
If OutRng.Count > 0 Then OutRng.ClearContents
End Sub
```

The code bellow worked for me for the active sheet.

```
Sub ClearUnlockedCells()

With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim OutRng As Range
Dim Rng As Range
On Error Resume Next
Set WorkRng = Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each Rng In WorkRng
    If Rng.Locked = False Then
        If OutRng.Count = 0 Then
            Set OutRng = Rng
        Else
            Set OutRng = Union(OutRng, Rng)
        End If
    End If
Next
If OutRng.Count > 0 Then OutRng.ClearContents

End Sub
```

EDIT: Just as a note, the code here helps with clearing the unprotected cells on the sheet even when they are mixed with protected cells. You do not have to specifically identify the unprotected cells.